# Android theme not affecting TextViews inside list item

Tags: android

I have a theme used throughout the app, in the theme the text color is simply declared like this:

`android:textColor="@android:color/black"`

For a TextView located inside of an activity the color is applied just fine. However when I create a TextView inside of a list item (inflated by an adapter) the text color is white instead.

Does anyone know what style needs to be declared in the theme for list items to be affected?

Full XML for the list item:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/lt_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lt_length"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/lt_checkbox"
    android:textSize="24dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/lt_length"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lt_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lt_subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

XML for the list:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/altl_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

And the adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LocalTrack track = getItem(position);

    ItemHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null || convertView.getTag() == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listem_track, parent, false);

        holder = new ItemHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lt_title);
        holder.length = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lt_length);
        holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lt_checkbox);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder = (ItemHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.title.setText(track.getTitle());
    holder.length.setText(Helpbot.convertMillisToTrackLength(track.getLength()));
    holder.checkbox.setChecked(mSelectedTracks.contains(track));

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: ListView and RawItem  xmls please?

Comment: @BhavikMehta question updated

Comment: in your Full XML for the list item, give android:textColor="@android:color/black" inside the <TextView/> where you want to show it black colored , else code is correct
or else specify the TextView name so i can build and answer for you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because you are inflating the row layout of your `ListView` with the `Context` of your `Application` (`LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());` or some other derivative), instead of using your `Activity`'s `Context`.

The difference between the Context you will get from `getApplicationContext()` and `Activity.this` lays in the implementation of `Context` for either of them.

Both `Context`, the `Application`'s `Context` and the `Activity`'s gets wrapped inside a `ContextWrapper` and proxy their calls to an internal "Base" `Context`.

The difference here is that the `Application` class is a singleton and only has one global implementation for your whole Application, while each Activity - since inheriting from `ContextWrapper` as well - has it's own unique implementation for each `Activity`.

Now that's why `getApplication()` doesn't - and can't - obey the rules of the themes you defined in your manifest, but the `Context` provided by your `Activity` does/can.

I highly recommend you to read Dave Smith's [article](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/) about `Context`s.

Answer (score 0):

**item_list_rs.xml**

This is use in ListAdapter for listview designe

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:background="@drawable/list_selector" 
 android:orientation="horizontal" 
 android:padding="5dip" > 

 <LinearLayout 
 android:id="@+id/thumbnail" 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
 android:layout_marginRight="5dip" 
 android:background="@drawable/image_bg" 
 android:padding="3dip" > 

 <ImageView 
 android:id="@+id/image_rs" 
 android:layout_width="80dip" 
 android:layout_height="100dip" 
  android:background="@drawable/image_bg" 
 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" /> ///////
 </LinearLayout> 

 <TextView 
 android:id="@+id/nama_rs" 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail" 
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail" 
 android:text="Dilip Birajadar" 
 android:textColor="#3dd63d" 
 android:textSize="12dip" 
 android:textStyle="bold" 
 android:typeface="sans" /> /////////



 <TextView 
 android:id="@+id/link_image_rs" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:visibility="gone" /> 

 <TextView 
 android:id="@+id/id_rs" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:visibility="gone" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tv_seling_price"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/thumbnail"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nama_rs"
     android:text="Selling Price"
      android:textSize="12dip"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:typeface="sans" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tv_measuring"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nama_rs"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     android:text="Additional-"
     android:textColor="#ad30f6"
      android:textSize="12dip"
     android:textStyle="bold" 
 android:typeface="sans" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/alamat_rs"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/telepon_rs"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     android:text="Information:"
     android:textColor="#000000"
     android:textSize="12dip" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/telepon_rs"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tv_seling_price"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_seling_price"
     android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_seling_price"
     android:text="Selling_price"
     android:textColor="#ff0000"
     android:textSize="11dip"
     android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ListAdapter.Java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader;
    public int[] daftar_rs;



    public ListAdapter(Pay_Per_View a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data = d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity

        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_rs, null);

        /*TextView id_rs = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.id_rs);*/
        TextView Image_name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.nama_rs);
        TextView link_image_rs = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.link_image_rs);
        TextView movie_price = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.telepon_rs);
    /*  TextView telepon_rs = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.alamat_rs);*/

        ImageView thumb_image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.image_rs);

        HashMap<String, String> daftar_rs = new HashMap<String, String>();
        daftar_rs = data.get(position);

        /*id_rs.setText(daftar_rs.get(Pay_Per_View.TAG_ID_RS));*/

        Image_name.setText(daftar_rs.get(Pay_Per_View.TAG_MOVIE_NAME));

        link_image_rs.setText(daftar_rs.get(Pay_Per_View.TAG_LINK_IMAGE_RS));

        movie_price.setText(daftar_rs.get(Pay_Per_View.TAG_MOVIE_PRICE));

        /*alamat_rs.setText(daftar_rs.get(MainActivity.TAG_MEASURING));

        */


        imageLoader.DisplayImage(daftar_rs.get(Pay_Per_View.TAG_LINK_IMAGE_RS),
                thumb_image);

        return vi;
    }

}
```

Comment: The idea is that I don't want to have to declare `android:textColor` for every textview inside of a list item

Comment: Yes for every text view inside the list item diffrent color we can define...@JMRboosties

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can set a default style for TextViews like this for all the app or activity,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/MyTextViewStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">#F00</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

and set the theme as your activity's theme.